# Open Limit Switch on Trane Furnace: How to fix?

Tags: hvac, repair

My 8 year old Trane Model tuh2d120a9v5va furnace is not giving out heat. The service people are all busy due to the recent storms. Through the little glass viewing window I see red and green flashing lights. The red flashes 4 times, the green 3 times, and these overlap. The panel inside says the 4 flashing red means an open limit switch.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Check your filter, clogged filter can cause the high limit to trip.

Comment: Sell your old control module on eBay : others can fix it,.

Comment: I rolled back the answer you put in your question post. That's not how we do things on Stack Exchange networks. Either provide an answer and accept it, or delete the question if you don't intend to follow up. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The high temp limit switches usually have a manual reset button that needs to be pressed to reset. I would try a reset it may have been a fluke that it tripped, if the reset dosent trip again it is probably fine. If it trips again you will want to verify the exhaust is clear, and the fan is freely spinning (some do need oil at each end to lube the bearings) low air flow on a high efficiency system can overheat the fire box.

Answer (score 2):

If the open high limit code flashes while the furnace is cold, pull one lead off and check its continuity with an ohmmeter. also check other devices in the same loop. Another way is to check the whole loop. Unplug the connector and check the resistance, pins 1 and 7 on XB80.

I have found in most cases the limit switch is fine. The problem is the Molex 12 pin connector in 90% of the cases we see with Trane. I clean the female part with a drill bit held in hand. The male part I try to scrape the outside as best I can, sometimes with a very small piece of sand paper. Then I coat with silicone dielectric grease. I see too many cases where it is recommended to replace the control board when the fault is just the connector.

Answer (score 2):

Update: A 1" flat capacitor in the fan control module was fried black and cracked.  A new module and $1000 later and the heat works again.  Perhaps power fluctuations due to a storm here caused some spikes that fried the module. I installed a whole house surge protector.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 airflows in a furnace and you need to make sure both of them are clear.  The first is the in house airflow, the cold air return bringing air into the furnace and the blower blowing it out through the vents.  This is typically NOT the air flow that the lights are indicating are blocked.
The second airflow is the air coming into the fire box/combustion chamber, providing oxygen to the burner and then the exhaust blowing out.  This IS the air flow the error lights are talking about.  When you get 4 blinking lights and the combustion chamber switches off automatically is may be as simple as wasps building a nest in the intake pipe during the summer.  In the fall when the furnace turns on, the nest gets sucked in a blocks the air from getting to the combustion chamber.  Typically, this pipe can be gently but firmly lifted straight up from the furnace.  There is typically caulking around it to secure it and you will be breaking the caulk when you lift it up, this does NOT harm your furnace.  But make sure it is not harming your roof.  Most of the time it is connected to a flexible exhaust run in your attic but rarely it is indeed going straight through your roof and you may need to caulk your roof after this procedure, so check the attic before you do this.
Once you life the pipe, get all the wasp nests out (there will be several) and then put it back together.  9 times out of ten this fixes the problem.  GLTA!